# Timestamps in human readable form

Tags: linux, macos, datetime, unix, command-line

Is there a way to pipe something that contains bunch of epoch/unix timestamp values and see text with datetime values converted to human readable form, something like:

```
$ cat data.txt
{
  "id": "20a68337-922b-4db0-85d6-719c97e0ee83",
  "published_at": 1457427709695,
  "expires": 1458346544
}

$ cat data.txt | convert-datetimes
{
  "id": "20a68337-922b-4db0-85d6-719c97e0ee83",
  "published_at": Tue, 08 Mar 2016 09:01:49.695 GMT,
  "expires": Wed, 18 May 2016 23:42:21 GMT
}
```

Comment: while they share much in common, this sort of Q clearly highlights (in one aspect) the differences between `linux`, `osX`, and `unix`. If you can reduce your Q to one version, you'll get a better answer. If you need a cross-platform solution, then please indicate that AND as always, best to show us what you have tried, so we can help correct your understandings. Can you use a new `gawk` on all platforms? That will simplify things (or perl etc for that matter). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Ideally I would love to find a solution which would work both in OS X and linux, since my host is a Mac and I do ssh into different linux machines quite a lot.

Comment: What time range do the timestamps need to cover?  Pre-2000?  Pre-1970?  Pre-1904?  Post-2038?  Is there a way to identify which 13-digit numbers are the times in milliseconds since the epoch and which are 13-digit ISBN numbers (or, in the old days, 13-digit credit card numbers)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ehhhrm.. I'm not very familiar with intricacies of timestamp formats, I guess I need something that would work similar to www.epochconverter.com

Comment: Well, since the data looks like it is JSON, you might need to parse it and look for selected names (such as "published_at" and "expires") and just map the following values (probably enclosing the formatted value in quotes since it is no longer a number and hence should be quoted per [JSON](http://json.org/)).  The issue of date range arises if you're dealing with birth dates or mortgage completion dates (30-year mortgages finish way past 2038, which is when 32-bit signed times have problems when the epoch is the Unix (POSIX) epoch: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00.

Comment: The key issue is 'which values should be passed to the variant on http://www.epochconverter.com/ that you devise'?  (I also observe that the epoch converter expects 10-digit numbers — seconds since the POSIX Epoch — and not 13-digit numbers (milliseconds).  Well, actually, it makes a (good) guess when `1463614941000` is specified that it is in milliseconds, but it can be confused by adding or removing zeros.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's purely coincidental that the example shown is json. I wonder if there's a command-line utility that would scan any given input, find anything that looks like epoch/unix timestamp, converted it and barf out the resulting text. I don't care about the format of finalized result, I just want to see all timestamps parsed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106771/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-agzam).

Comment: `date -d @1457427709` (Linux) or `date -r 1457427709` (OS X) can be used to convert seconds-since-the-epoch to a formatted time.  If it is milliseconds-since-the-epoch then you'd need to add on the milliseconds separately.

Answer (score 4):

This is fundamentally a poorly-defined problem, because timestamps are just numbers, and any number corresponds to *some* time. So you have to define some heuristic for what values are plausible timestamps.

Once you have such a heuristic, if you're not trying to preserve the structure of your input (JSON in your example), just take your favorite text-munging language and implement it. For example, we could just assume that any number with the right number of digits (for milliseconds or seconds) is OK.

Of course, the right number of digits changes over time, but it's not going to increase until the year 2286, by which I hope this will be long obsolete.

Python:

```
import re, sys, time

def reformat(match):
    timestamp = int(match.group(1))
    if timestamp >= 1e12:
        timestamp /= 1000.0
    return time.asctime(time.gmtime(timestamp))

for line in sys.stdin:
  sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r"\b(\d{10,14})\b", reformat, line))
```

Perl 5:

```
while (<>) {
  s/\b(\d{10,12})\b/gmtime $1/ge;
  s!\b(\d{13,14})\b!gmtime($1 / 1000)!ge;
  print;
}
```

Improvements:

- If you know things about the timestamps you expect to see, such as that they are all within some range of the current time, then you could add a condition (in the replacement function) that returns the original string unedited if the numeric value is out of range.
- You could tighten up the regular expression to check the nearby characters, like skipping anything with a "-" preceding it.
- If the input actually is JSON or another structured syntax, you could actually parse the input and look for timestamps only where you expect them (or generically, like not matching digits inside any string value).